# Two Crystal Ball Problem O(sqrt(n)) solution not working in all cases

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

GHere is the Two Crystal Ball problem: Given two crystal balls that will break if dropped from high enough distance, determine the exact spot in which it will break in the most optimized way. Solution: To understand the problem, let us assume the crystal ball will break if dropped from a height of 8 meters. So, if we drop from true meter, the ball will not break(false). If dropped from height of 2 meter, again the ball will not break(false). We keep on doing it. When dropped from 8 meters, the ball will break(true). If we list all falses and trues in an array, it will look like below:
[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ,false, false, false, true, true, true, true] –

so you should find the first true I tried to solve it using the methode from front end master course but I founded it doesn't work in all the cases in that case as an exemple it's give me -1 but if i add new false it give me the first place of true boolean which is 31 is there any way to improve that algorithm and thank you

```js
function two_crystal_balls(breaks) {
  const jmpAmount = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(breaks.length));

  let i = jmpAmount
  for (i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount;) {
    if (breaks[i]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(i, "i")

  i -= jmpAmount
  console.log(i, "i")

  for (let j = 0; j < jmpAmount && i < breaks.length; j++, i++) {
    if (breaks[i]) {
      console.log(j, "i")
      return i
    }
  }
  return -1
}

console.log(two_crystal_balls([false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]))
```

Comment: How do you determine the height? What is the Crystal Ball Problem? Are you sure the `for` loop is correct? I would say `for(i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount;) {` should be `for(;i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount) {`.

Comment: the sytnex is correct the for(i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount;) is the same doesn't change anything

Comment: imo. the optimal solution should be a binary search

Comment: but binary search still linear

Comment: No, binary search is logarithmic.

Comment: If this is the “egg dropping” puzzle then the optimal solution involves triangular numbers, which is not exactly the square and its inverse is therefore not exactly the square root.  But right now it doesn’t look like the question is clear enough; please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: yeah i know but will search the half of the array because it's sorted so it will be linear

Comment: the question is the algorithm it didn't find the first true boolean in all cases it's depend on the data of how many false not always work

Comment: Binary search is not linear, it’s logarithmic. But you can’t use a binary search because you’re not allowed to get more than two “too high” results; the egg/ball breaks and you only have two of them.

Comment: in this case it will be linear

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding the wording in the question and the comments; it’s clear that there is a language barrier so I’m not 100% sure how to proceed.  I recommend you [edit] the question to clarify the issue in as simple and direct a manner as possible. Describe the problem, describe the expected input/output relationship, and provide concrete examples of expected outputs to specific inputs.  Good luck!

Comment: Binary searches are not linear in this case or in any case. If you could do a binary search then you’d get an answer in log_2 the size of the input.  But you can’t, so it’s on the order of sqrt.

Comment: Here is the Two Crystal Ball problem:

Given two crystal balls that will break if dropped from high enough distance, determine the exact spot in which it will break in the most optimized way.

Solution:

To understand the problem, let us assume the crystal ball will break if dropped from a height of 8 meters. So, if we drop from true meter, the ball will not break(false). If dropped from height of 2 meter, again the ball will not break(false). We keep on doing it. When dropped from 8 meters, the ball will break(true). If we list all falses and trues in an array, it will look like below:

Comment: Please add it to the question, not as a comment under the question.

Comment: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ,false, false, false, true, true, true, true]

Comment: Why do you start the second loop at `let j = 0`. It should be `let j = i - jmpAmount`. You've already tested until `i` and the first ball broke at the `i`-th floor. You know the solution has to be between `i - jmpAmount` and `i`. Search for "two egg problem" and you'll find multiple duplicates.

Comment: i want to go back in a square and iterate the breaks based on jmpAmount

Comment: Not that this really matters, but the optimal answer is more like half the square root, as shown [in this demonstration](https://tsplay.dev/mL8zVm).  It's the triangular numbers; you should lower your jump amount by one for each drop you do.  But I guess if we're just looking for O(sqrt(n)) instead of the actual optimal algorithm then ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems in your code.

1. The first loop is not correct. A `for` loop has the syntax

   ```
   for (initialization; condition; afterthought)
   ```

   The loop

   ```
   for (i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount;) {
   ```

   should be

   ```
   for (; i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount) {
   ```
2. The loop

   ```
   for (let j = 0; j < jmpAmount && i < breaks.length; j++, i++) {
     if (breaks[i]) {
       console.log(j, "i")
       return i
     }
   }
   ```

   should be

   ```
   for (let j = i; j < breaks.length; j++) {
     if (breaks[j]) {
       console.log(j, "i");
       return j;
     }
   }
   ```
3. `j` contains the solution, not `i`.

The fixed code:

```js
function two_crystal_balls(breaks) {
  const jmpAmount = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(breaks.length));

  let i = jmpAmount;
  for (; i < breaks.length; i += jmpAmount) {
    if (breaks[i]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(i, "i");

  i -= jmpAmount;
  console.log(i, "i");

  for (let j = i; j < breaks.length; j++) {
    if (breaks[j]) {
      console.log(j, "i");
      return j;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(two_crystal_balls([false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]))
```

Comment: the first loop start with jmpAmount and not 0 becuase always the first will be false and in progress it will start to become true so i want only the first true and the rest will be always true it ends to early because of that i don't care about the rest

Comment: @YoussefArika Your second loop iterates from `j = 0` to `j < jmpAmount` but you know that the result is between `i - jmpAmount` and `i`, which can be larger than `jmpAmount`. The loop starts too early and ends too early.

Comment: @YoussefArika Remember to accept answers that answered your question. I'm currently seeing, that you already subtracted `i -= jmpAmount;`. That's correct and you shouldn't subtract it again in the loop.

Comment: how i can accept the answer, so i let j = 0 ?

Comment: @YoussefArika Click the green check mark at the top left of the answer. _"so `i let j = 0` ?"_ No, I fixed my answer. It's `let j = i`. `let j = 0` makes this a linear search and discards the earlier progress.

Comment: i couldnn't find the checkmark i enterend the answer from notification

Comment: how do you see these algorithm better than the binary or not ?

Comment: @YoussefArika This algorithm is much worse than binary search, but you can't use binary search here.

Comment: yes that is the problem and only the better answer than the linear

Comment: Not that this really matters, but the optimal answer is more like half the square root, as shown [in this demonstration](https://tsplay.dev/mL8zVm).  It's the triangular numbers; you should lower your jump amount by one for each drop you do.  But I guess if we're just looking for O(sqrt(n)) instead of the actual optimal algorithm then ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. This puzzle was new for me. I learned about it when you mentioned it in the comments. I try to understand your comment and fix my answer when I succeed.